# how do list to string in python

Tags: python

```
    import itertools
    import string

    def crackdict(max, min=1, chars=None):
 assert max >= min >= 1

 if chars is None:
  import string
  chars = string.printable[:-5]

 p = []
 for i in xrange(min, max + 1):
  p.append(itertools.product(string.printable[:-5], repeat=i))

 return itertools.chain(*p)

    #Just for test：
    max, min = 4, 1
    d = crackdict(max, min)
```

i want to print the result like this
0
1
2
3
4
5
6

but now the print like [('0',), ('1',), ('2',), ('3',), ('4',), ('5',), ('6',), ('7',), ('8',), ('9',), ('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',), ('e',), ('f',), ('g',), ('h',), ('i',), ('j',), ('k',), ('l',), ('m',), ('n',), ('o',), ('p',), ('q',), ('r',), ('s',), ('t',), ('u',), ('v',), ('w',), ('x',), ('y',), ('z',), ('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('E',), ('F',), ('G',), ('H',), ('I',), ('J',), ('K',), ('L',), ('M',), ('N',), ('O',), ('P',), ('Q',), ('R',), ('S',), ('T',), ('U',), ('V',), ('W',), ('X',), ('Y',), ('Z',), ('!',), ('"',), ('#',), ('$',), ('%',), ('&',), ("'",), ('(',), (')',), ('*',), ('+',), (',',), ('-',), ('.',), ('/',), (':',), (';',), ('<',), ('=',), ('>',), ('?',), ('@',), ('[',), ('\',), (']',), ('^',), ('_',), ('`',), ('{',), ('|',), ('}',), ('~',), (' ',), ('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('0', '2'), ('0', '3'), ('0', '4'), ('0', '5'), ('0', '6'), ('0', '7'), ('0', '8'), ('0', '9'), ('0', 'a'), ('0', 'b'), ('0', 'c'), ('0', 'd'), ('0', 'e'), ('0', 'f'), ('0', 'g'), ('0', 'h'), ('0', 'i'), ('0', 'j'), ('0', 'k'), ('0', 'l'), ('0', 'm'), ('0', 'n'), ('0', 'o'), ('0', 'p'), ('0', 'q'), ('0', 'r'), ('0', 's'), ('0', 't'), ('0', 'u'), ('0', 'v'), ('0', 'w'), ('0', 'x'), ('0', 'y'), ('0', 'z'), ('0', 'A'), ('0', 'B'), ('0', 'C'), ('0', 'D'), ('0', 'E'), ('0', 'F'), ('0', 'G'), ('0', 'H'), ('0', 'I'), ('0', 'J'), ('0',

how can i do it ?
thanks!

Comment: How is `('1', '2', '3')` similar in any way to "aaaaaa"?  Do you think you could make your example consistent with itself?

Comment: i want to the list translate to string 
like this  ('1','2','3')
123

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'abc'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
return [''.join(itertools.product(chars, repeat=i)) for i in xrange(min, max + 1)]
```

instead of everything in the function starting from `p = []`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `"delimiter".join(list)`

```
a_list = ["Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"]
a_str = " ".join(a_list)    # " " is the delimiter
b_str = "-".join(a_list)    # "-" is the delimiter
c_str = "".join(a_list)     # ""  is the delimiter
print(a_str)
print(b_str)
print(c_str)
```

Output :

**Hello Stack Overflow**

**Hello-Stack-Overflow**

**HelloStackOverflow**