# How can I print Chinese characters in the console?

Tags: python

I am a little confused when I want to print Chinese characters in Python console:

For example, let's say I read some Chinese characters `尽管美国一些重要行业` in a list `word_list`. If I print like this:

```
for item in word_list:
    print item
```

It displays the Chinese characters as `尽` `管` `美` `国` `一` `些` `重` `要` `行` `业` in the console. However, if I directly print like this:

```
print word_list
```

I got: `[u'\u5c3d\u7ba1', u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'\u4e00\u4e9b', u'\u91cd\u8981', u'\u884c\u4e1a', ...`

So how can I just print the `word_list` and let it displays in Chinese characters?

Comment: `''.join(word_list)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do list to string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3191162/how-do-list-to-string-in-python)

Comment: Do you want to print them as list items with chinese chars or *joined* in one string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
print ''.join(word_list)
```

Here `join` will concatenate each two consecutive elements from `word_list` with `''` char(which is the Empty string), which is as putting all element in `word_list` together in one string. In your case, the element of `word_list` are already in unicode format, so it was straight forward.

```
>>> l = [u'\u5c3d\u7ba1', u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'\u4e00\u4e9b', u'\u91cd\u8981', u'\u884c\u4e1a']
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print ''.join(l)
尽管美国一些重要行业
>>> print l
[u'\u5c3d\u7ba1', u'\u7f8e\u56fd', u'\u4e00\u4e9b', u'\u91cd\u8981', u'\u884c\u4e1a']
>>> for i in l:
    print i 
尽管
美国
一些
重要
行业
```

Comment: It is so cool. I also wish to ask why it succeed in printing Chinese characters by just add a ` `?

Comment: @flyingmouse...can you elaborate more?...or are you talking about my answer?

Comment: yes, I am talking your answer, it solved my problem.

Comment: See my edited answer..and @flyingmouse...if you are happy with it, consider accepting it.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I have a further question? Why I just `print word_list` can not display the characters?

Comment: That's because `word_list` is a *list* object not a string object...and what you see after `print word_list` are the character mapping of the chineses chars into unicode. I have added an example for you.